# Problem to understand $f(A\backslash B)\neq f(A)\backslash f(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that $f(A)\backslash f(B)\subset f(A\backslash B)$.

Indeed, $$y\in f(A)\backslash f(B)\implies \Big(\exists x\in A\backslash B: y=f(x)\Big)\implies y\in f(A\backslash B).$$

But to me, $$y\in f(A\backslash B)\implies \Big(\exists x\in A\backslash B: y=f(x)\Big)\implies y\in f(A)\backslash f(B).$$

What wrong here ?

Comment: What happens when $f$ is constant?

Comment: How do you get from $x\in A\setminus B :y=f(x)$ to $y\in f(A)\setminus f(B)$? That's mere assertion.

Answer (score 1):

The statement $y\in f(A)\setminus f(B)$ is equivalent to the statement:

> (There exists $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=y$) and (**for all** $b\in B$, $f(b)\neq y$.)

This means that the $a\in A$ in necessarily not in $B$, so $a\in A\setminus B$. (This step you leave out of your proof of the first direction, but it is an important step, because it is a step that cannot be reversed.)

So, that's how you get $ y\in f(A)\setminus f(B)$ implies $y\in f(A\setminus B)$, but that argument cannot be reversed.

just pick $f$ constant to see how your argument fails. Then $f(A)\setminus f(B)=\emptyset$ if $B$ is non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

Why the fact that $$\exists x\in A\backslash B: y=f(x)$$
would implies that $y\notin f(B)$ ? It's true only if $f$ is injective, otherwise, it's wrong ! Example are numerous (as said **Thomas Andrew** :  $f(x)=1$ with $A=[0,2]$ and $B=[1,3]$).